# How can I remove leftover bits of kde-standard?

Tags: kde, desktop-environments

I've been looking into different desktop environments, so I decided I'd give kde a try instead of the normal Unity. I installed kde through:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-standard
```

Re-logged and everything went fine booted into KDE and had a look around. After a while, I wanted to uninstall it so I executed:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kde-standard
```

then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But the default log in screen is still kde.. and I can still boot into it.

Comment: @UriHerrera Actually, that question and answer are quite old.  I don't think that works anymore, plus the OP installed `kde-standard ` which is different from `kubuntu-desktop` which is what that question is about.

Comment: @Seth How different?

Comment: @UriHerrera Very different.  `kubuntu-desktop` has *waay* more packages than `kde-standard`.

Comment: @Seth Wouldn't then removing the packages listed in the other question be an overkill for this one?.

Comment: @UriHerrera No, you would just get total errors.  I tried it recently, it doesn't work.

Comment: @UriHerrera Uhm.. I did have a look about before asking. Please don't assume I am ignorant to searching and then continue post things which don't help at all. No need for the harsh tone. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you install then uninstall desktop environments you get a lot of left overs.

Start by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge   akregator dragonplayer gwenview juk kaddressbook kamera kate kcalc
  kde-baseapps kde-baseapps-bin kde-plasma-desktop kde-standard kde-wallpapers
  kdeplasma-addons kdm kfind kmail knotes konq-plugins konqueror
  konqueror-nsplugins kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer kscreensaver
  kscreensaver-xsavers kwalletmanager kwrite libcalendarsupport4
  libeventviews4 libgadu3 libgpgme++2 libgrantlee-core0 libincidenceeditorsng4
  libkateinterfaces4 libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdgantt2
  libkexiv2-11 libkexiv2-data libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkonqsidebarplugin4a
  libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkpgp4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libktnef4
  libmailcommon4 libmailimporter4 libmarblewidget14 libmediastreamer1
  libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4
  libmsn0.3 libopenconnect2 libortp8 libotr2 libqgpgme1 libqoauth1 libsrtp0
  libtemplateparser4 libtidy-0.99-0 marble-data marble-plugins
  plasma-containments-addons plasma-dataengines-addons
  plasma-desktopthemes-artwork plasma-runners-addons plasma-wallpapers-addons
  plasma-widget-lancelot plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons
  polkit-kde-1 sweeper xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-gl
```

If you get any errors, thats usually a good sign.

Then:

```
sudo apt-get purge svgpart kdepim-kresources kde-plasma-netbook skanlite kleopatra spamassassin
  bogofilter spambayes bsfilter crm114 clamav procmail kdeartwork-emoticons
  texlive-latex-base libotr2-bin srtp-utils network-manager-vpnc
```

Then try `sudo apt-get autoremove` again.

That should remove everything and put your computer pretty much back to the state it was in before you installed kde.

Comment: Looks like it worked, just running autoremove now. Is the restarting problem I described a common one? I found it strange.

Comment: @user132010 Can't tell at this point.  It will depend on your hardware.

Comment: @user132010 That's great!  If somehow that restarting problem crops back up, you should ask a new question about it :)

Comment: @Seth I think a disclaimer would fit well in your answer. The OP might actually depend on some of these libs.

Comment: @Private That's what I've heard.  I myself have never missed anything... wouldn't `apt-get upgrade` install them if needed?

Comment: @Seth Not sure, but it would seem logical. If you first do an auto-remove, however, you might also remove packages that *because* of missing libraries have become obsolete. Can you find out? Can also give your source for your list of packages? Is it from http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu?

Comment: @Private I ran "sudo apt-get install kde-standard"  then pressed "n"  at the prompt. That way I got a list of everything it would install.   Everything in the answer was something it was going to install.  That's why I don't think it will hurt anything.

Comment: hi seth, maybe you should edit that in your answer... your setup is not someone else's. good way of finding out which packages though...

Comment: @Private Removing these packages ins't going to hurt anything unless you have some KDE apps installed that rely on these.  This is the best (and only way AFAIK) to remove this stuff.  So, like I said, unless you have KDE apps, nothing should happen.